# custom dialogue box buttons in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Message box with Validate and Cancel buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519451/message-box-with-validate-and-cancel-buttons)

Wanted to ask if its possible to make a dialogue box with custom buttons in C#, say instead of "YesNoCancel" to have something like "Buy,Demo,Contact" ?

Thanks!

Comment: This can be done by displaying a form ( instead of a message box ) and sending simply sending the response to determine which one was sent.  This also allows you to be able to avoid blocking the main thread ( a message box would normally not allow you to move the main form until a response to the dialog was given ).

Comment: duplicated post: [Open button on Messagebox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6648599/323339)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a form and put whatever buttons or other controls you'd like.

The standard message box, which you seem to be referring to, does not provide hooks to set non-standard buttons.

If you prefer, you can even create your form from code, allowing you to add any number of custom buttons depending on your arguments. An example of creating a form from code can be seen [here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/winforms/dynamically-creating-a-winforms-dialog).

Answer (score -1):

Making your own custom dialog box is a great idea. I am actually in the middle of creating one in WPF. The nice thing about  this approach is that you then have the flexibility to do whatever you want for buttons/icons/etc. For example, you could make a show method that accepts a string array for the buttons, and then the names of the buttons could be whatever you like. A call might look like this:

```
CustomMessageBox.Show("the text", "the caption", new string[]{"Buy", "Demo", "Contact"});
```